# "Mapping" scanl

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

Given a list `:: [(Foo, Bar)]`, I'd like to perform a scanl1 on the `Bar`s, but preserve their `Foo` "tags".

I.e. I'd like a function with the type `:: [(a, b)] -> ([b] -> [c]) -> [(a, c)]`, so that I can pass a curried `scanl1` as the second argument.

I can write it recursively, but it feels like there's a way to compose higher-order functions to do this.

Is this already possible with standard functions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of writing an unsatisfying higher order function, you could lift your combining function to thread the `Foo` tags through so you can still use `scanl1` , which is what you mean.

```
keeptags :: (Bar -> Bar -> Bar) -> (Foo,Bar) -> (Foo,Bar) -> (Foo,Bar)
keeptags g (_,b) (a',b') = (a',g b b')
```

Now you can use `scanl1`; take your original `qux :: Bar -> Bar -> Bar` and make

```
scanQux :: [(Foo,Bar)] -> [(Foo,Bar)]
scanQux = scanl1 (keeptags qux)
```

`keeptags` is simple and `scanQux` is crystal clear.

For example, if

```
type Foo = Char
type Bar = Int

qux = (+)
```

then you get

```
*Main> scanl1 qux [1..9]
[1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45]

*Main> zip "HELLO MUM" [1..9]
[('H',1),('E',2),('L',3),('L',4),('O',5),(' ',6),('M',7),('U',8),('M',9)]

*Main> scanQux $ zip "HELLO MUM" [1..9]
[('H',1),('E',3),('L',6),('L',10),('O',15),(' ',21),('M',28),('U',36),('M',45)]
```

as you had hoped.

Answer (score 4):

You mean, `unzip`?

http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputprelude/unzip_f.html

```
x = zip a c
  where
    (a, b) = unzip my_list
    c = what_ever_you_want_on b
```

Comment: That gets me as far as `((uncurry zip) . (\(a,b) -> (a, scanl1 f b)) . unzip)`, but it still feels like there's an easier way...

Comment: @amindfv: With [`import Control.Arrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html), you can write `uncurry zip . second (scanl1 f) . unzip`; [`second`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow.html#v:second) applies a function to the second half of a tuple.  The types in `Control.Arrow` are complicated, but if you just read `Arrow a => a b c` as `b -> c`, the module contains an excellent collection of combinators for writing point-free functions and/or working with tuples.

Comment: @AntalS-Z: That's great to know. I think it deserves to be put as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

My friend came with the following implementation for `keeptags`:

```
import Control.Arrow

keeptags g (_,b) = second (g b)
```

I think it's still readable.

Comment: This is great - clean and simple!